# Google App Engine: Query to see default version

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I remotely query a GAE application to see it's current default version?
Not manually.

Comment: Assuming you're asking for Java language, the [Module API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService#getDefaultVersion-java.lang.String-) provides the method `getDefaultVersion`. With a specific module or using `default` for the main module, you can retrieve the default version. After that, you can create and endpoint to query this value.

Comment: ...and similarly in Python, with `google.appengine.api.modules.modules`. Note, for precision's sake, that's there is no "default version* of an *application*, but rather of a *module*; but, if you're not explicitly using modules, you'll have a single module named `default`, and `get_default_version()` called w/o arguments will be running in that default module, thus return *its* version.